# google calendar after url import only shows the last event

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar, rfc2445, rfc5545

I'm trying to make an .ics file and by URL import put the events into google calendar. But the problem is that after I import them to google calendar it only show the last event. I don't understand what am I doing wrong I even exported a calendar from GC and tried to generate my calendar to look exactly as the exported one.

Here is the URL to the .ics file:
http://bme.hracsi.net/includes/download.php?sub=2,3,4&sem=2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your events have the same UID
RFC5545 §3.8.4.7 specifies "UID" itself MUST be a globally unique identifier.

to make it work you must change this property value.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
...
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
UID:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
...
UID:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
UID:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
...
UID:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
UID:d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Thanks it helped a lot now it's working with google calendar.Now the only problem is that if I download it and open with Outlook the hours are incorrect. In the begining it's add +1 hour to the events and after the daylight saving +2 hours. What do I do wrong?

Comment: it is because your `DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Budapest:20130314T070000Z` is illegal: Z means Zulu = UTC which is not Europe/Budapest. you should change to `DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Budapest:20130314T070000`